# How to itemize my references in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

Well, the current style of my paper seems like:

> Eneko Agirre, Daniel Cer, Mona Diab, and Aitor Gonzalez-Agirre. Semeval-2012 task6: A pilot on semantic textual similarity. In* SEM 2012: The First Joint Conferenceon Lexical and Computational Semantics–Volume 1: Proceedings of the main con-ference and the shared task, and Volume 2: Proceedings of the Sixth InternationalWorkshop on Semantic Evaluation (SemEval 2012), pages 385–393, 2012.
>
> Eneko Agirre, Daniel Cer, Mona Diab, Aitor Gonzalez-Agirre, and Weiwei Guo. *sem 2013 shared task: Semantic textual similarity. InSecond Joint Conference onLexical and Computational Semantics (* SEM), Volume 1: Proceedings of the MainConference and the Shared Task: Semantic Textual Similarity, pages 32–43, 2013.

What I need is:

> [1] Eneko Agirre, Daniel Cer, Mona Diab, and Aitor Gonzalez-Agirre. Semeval-2012 task6: A pilot on semantic textual similarity. In* SEM 2012: The First Joint Conferenceon Lexical and Computational Semantics–Volume 1: Proceedings of the main con-ference and the shared task, and Volume 2: Proceedings of the Sixth InternationalWorkshop on Semantic Evaluation (SemEval 2012), pages 385–393, 2012.
>
> [2] Eneko Agirre, Daniel Cer, Mona Diab, Aitor Gonzalez-Agirre, and Weiwei Guo. *sem 2013 shared task: Semantic textual similarity. InSecond Joint Conference onLexical and Computational Semantics (* SEM), Volume 1: Proceedings of the MainConference and the Shared Task: Semantic Textual Similarity, pages 32–43, 2013.
>   The Latex code that I used is:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{ref}
```

The minimal working example is available at link【http://www.kitgram.cn/downloads/something/MWE.zip】.

Comment: Please post the relevant LaTeX code in the body of your query. Hyperlinks to external documents can and do eventually decay, making your posting worthless to future readers.

Comment: Incidentally, the zip file does *not* seem accessible to a computer that uses a VPN to link to the Internet. All the more reason to be become suspicious of why you use a web service that won't allow access via a VPN. As a matter of firm policy, I *refuse* to deal with websites that do not allow access via a VPN. I value my computer and the data stored on my computer, and I will certainly not open it up to uncontrolled attacks.

Comment: I am not sure the reason which raises the issue so that the computer cannot access the link via a VPN. Althought the main .tex document cannot contain all essential information that you need to solve the problem, I will upload the code in the body of my query.

Comment: Thanks for indicating which bibliography style you employ. Does your document load the `natbib` package? If so, with which options?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used natbib. I have reupdated my query, please check it for further information.

Comment: The `cite` and `natbib` citation management packages are not mutually compatible. Use one or the other, *but not both*. If you decide to stick with `natbib`, be sure to specify the option `numbers` as well and then run a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more).

Comment: I am a fresman of Latex. So, if I decide to use natbib, which command should I use to set the option ```number``` ?

Comment: The option is `numbers`, not `number`: `\usepackage[numbers,<any other options>]{natbib}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! your solution works perfectly!